# Quero personalizar as mensagens de errors geradas dentro de um array de objetos no validator do AdonisJS. Agradeço por qualquer ajuda

Tags: javascript, node.js, adonisjs

Quero personalizar as mensagens de erros do validator do adonisJS ao validar um array de objetos existentes.
Porém não estou conseguindo acessar essas validações para personalizar as mensagens

Esse é meu código do validator:

```
users: schema.array().members(
      schema.object().members({
        user_id: schema.number([
          rules.exists({
            table: 'users',
            column: 'id'
          })
        ])
      })
    ),
```

Estou tentando personalizar a mensagem dessa maneira:

```
public messages = {
    ...this.messages,
    'users.*.user_id.exists': 'Usuário não existe!',
 }
```

O que está sendo gerado:

```
{
    "message": "hasValidationErrors",
    "errors": {
        "users": {
            "0": [],
            "1": []
        }
    }
}
```